# AttributeError: module 'nltk' has no attribute 'download'

Tags: python, nltk

I am using a mac and have not been able to access any of the nltk files I have downloaded. All of the files are on my computer downloaded using terminal. No matter what I try to access or how I write it, I always get an attribute error saying nltk has no attribute download. [This is an example of some of the code I have put in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LVA9T.png)

Comment: Hmm, this is odd. How did you install @Liv?

Comment: Did you name any of your script `nltk.py` in the same directory? Also, what's your output for `import os; os.listdir('.')`.

Answer (score 2):

Try running `sudo /Applications/Python\ 3.6/Install\ Certificates.command` in terminal

[Credit to Alvations](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/issues/1961)

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately, I have tried that and it didn't do anything.

Comment: hmmm -- how did you install nltk?

Answer (score 0):

Following these steps worked for me. Run in command line:

```
> pip uninstall nltk
> pip install -U nltk
```

Answer (score 0):

It's simple, load corpora: It worked for me.
Open python interpreter by opening terminal or anaconda command prompt and type 'python' without quotation; ex: `C:\Users\UserName>python`.
Then type:
`>>> import nltk` and
`>>> nltk.download()`
Choose and install all or some corpora. If you don't know what exactly causing the error, you can download all packages.
You can also check [here](https://www.nltk.org/install.html).